# How to show QRC scan results on Input text

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

Am trying out barcode scanning/reader in phonegap. I have managed to read the QR codes but now am stack on how I can show results on the input text.

Js for Scanning

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function scan()
    {
               cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
              function (result) {
              var qrc = result.text; 
                  alert("We got a barcode\n" +
                        "Result: " + result.text + "\n" +
                        "Format: " + result.format + "\n" +
                        "Cancelled: " + result.cancelled + "\n" +
                        "QRC: " + qrc); 
              }, 
              function (error) {
                  alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
              });
    }
    </script>
```

The variable qrc is being alerted properly, but trouble is on how to show this on my input text.

Body content

```
    <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <a href="" data-role="button" onclick="scan()" >Scan</a>

    <form id="Insert"  method="POST">
    <input type="text"  name="qrc"  id="qrc" value=""/><br>
    <input type="submit"  value="Post" id="submit">
   </form>
    </div>
```

When QRC is scanned results, I want the text input populated with the results.

Answer (score 1):

We can assign a value to text fields, like this  `$('#qrc').val(qrc);` 
if you are not using jquery then  `document.getElementById("qcr").value = qcr;`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            function scan()
        {
                   cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
                  function (result) {
                  var qrc = result.text; 
                      alert("We got a barcode\n" +
                            "Result: " + result.text + "\n" +
                            "Format: " + result.format + "\n" +
                            "Cancelled: " + result.cancelled + "\n" +
                            "QRC: " + qrc); 
                          $('#qrc').val(qrc); // Added this line

                  }, 
                  function (error) {
                      alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
                  });
        }
        </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function scan(){   
       cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
              function (result) {
               var qrc = result.text;         
               document.getElementById("qrc").value=qrc.toString();

             }, 
              function (error) {
                  alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
              });
    }
</script>
```