# How to show NFC scan results on Input text

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, phonegap

Am trying out NFC reading in phonegap. I have managed to read the NFC but now am stack on how I can show results on the input text. I got help on [How to show QRC scan results on Input text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50597938/how-to-show-qrc-scan-results-on-input-text) but the problem is the implementation of "$('#v')=val.(vv);" breaks or deactivates NFC reading. Is there another way in which I can get these values...

Js for Reading

```
     onDeviceReady: function() {
         app.receivedEvent('deviceready');

    // Read NDEF formatted NFC Tags
    nfc.addTagDiscoveredListener  (
        function (nfcEvent) {
            var tag = nfcEvent.tag,
                ndefMessage = tag.ndefMessage;

            alert(JSON.stringify(ndefMessage));

            alert(nfc.bytesToString(ndefMessage[0].payload).substring(3));

            //Getting values on Input
        var vv = (nfc.bytesToString(ndefMessage[0].payload).substring(3));
        $('#v')=val.(vv);         -----this breaks the reading.

        },
        function () { // success callback
            alert("Waiting for NDEF tag");
        },
        function (error) { // error callback
            alert("Error adding NDEF listener " + JSON.stringify(error));
        }
    );
    }
```

Input Form as follows:

```
    <form id="Insert"  method="POST">
    <input type="text"  name="v"  id="v" value=""/>   ---------Values of NFC should show here after the alert
   </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

it breaks the reading because that's not the right code to change the input value, try this:

```
$('#v').val(vv);
```

Comment: Great stuff! wonder why" $('#v')=val.(vv);" works under some functions..

Comment: You're welcome! You may also accept the answer as "accepted answer" to help other users too :)